# Number of Technical Architects

Tags: certification

Just out of curiosity,can anyone tell me the  number of certified Technical Architects are there? Is there anyplace where it displays a list of this certification holders?

Answer (score 11):

According to [this list](http://www.asagarwal.com/the-elite-club-of-salesforce-com-certified-technical-architects), there are 103. I do not know how accurate it is.

Comment: Unfortunately this list is nearly a year old but maybe the best you can get.

Comment: @UweHeim "*the list is correct and up to date (as of 8-Aug-2014)*"

Comment: But based on his personal research in public, non salesforce , resources. It's definitely not complete. In un-official comments I've heared/seen that there were at least 200< (excluding salesforce) in 2013.

Comment: Agreed. It is by no means a verifiable number.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know that's not information Salesforce gives out publicly. While I too would find it interesting to see such numbers (or per region).

I believe the [verification page is the only public resource.](http://certification.salesforce.com/verification) There you're limited to looking up a person and viewing which certifications they have.

Answer (score 0):

As of Dreamforce 2016, it was less than 250.

Suzanne Ford gave a couple of CTA presentations and she mentioned that number in those.